# Determine the ideal class group of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-78})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The question is to determine the ideal class groups of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-78})$. Well, by the Minkowski bound, we just need to check for ideals such that:

$N(I) \leq \dfrac{4\sqrt{-78}}{\pi}
 \leq 11$

Now:

$N(I) = 1 \Rightarrow I = O_{K}$

$N(I) = 2,$  since $-78 \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow I = p_{2} = (2,\sqrt{-78}), p_{2}^{2} = (2)$ and it is not principal since $a^{2} + 78b^{2} = 2$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$.

$N(I) = 3 \Rightarrow p_{3} = (3, \sqrt{-78}), p_{3}^{2} = (3)$

$N(I) = 4 = 2.2 \Rightarrow I = p_{2}^{2} = (4)$

$N(I) = 5, 5$ is inert, therefore there is not ideal of norm $5$

$N(I) = 6 \Rightarrow I = p_{2}p_{3}$ and it is not principal since $a^{2} + 78b^{2} = 6$ is not solvable in $\mathbb{Z}$

$N(I) = 7, 7$ is inert, same as $5$

$N(I) = 8 \Rightarrow I = p_{2}^{8}$

$N(I) = 9 \Rightarrow I = p_{3}^{2}$

$N(I) = 10 = 2 \times 5$ no ideals with norm $10$, since there are no ideals of norm $5$

$N(I) = 11, 11$ is inert, thus no ideals of norm $11$.

So we can conclude that $Cl(K) \leq 5$. Since $p_{2}$ has order 2 $\Rightarrow Cl(K) = 2$ or $4$.

Now I am having problems in going further. I know that every ideal has norm $2$. So I don`t know if $Cl(K) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ or $Cl(K) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

Comment: you say you have $p_2,p_3$ non-principal, and that $p_2p_3$ is not principal, so the class group looks like $V_4$